# How can I change number format and alias in javascript API legend?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to change the alias and the length of a field that already exists in my GDB from the Javascript API. Is this possible?

I see that `alias` is a property of the `Field` class. Can I do something like `featureLayer.field["fieldName"].alias = "fieldAlias"`?

EDIT: I've changed the alias of the field in ArcMap and that persists in the feature service. But, I'm still wondering: How do I change the number format used in the dijit Legend? (I would like to display rounded numbers and percentages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias is being read from the underlying database, so you need to change the alias in the feature class.  The alias property is just a read only value of a field in the JavaScript API.

Comment: Okay I'll change it back in GIS then. I'm changing this in order to control what is displayed in the legend widget. I'm also hoping to show round numbers in the legend and % for certain fields. How do I do this in GIS?

Comment: You'll have to stop the Service and then you can use either [Alter Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000) or you can do this in the Feature Class properties in the Fields tab.

Comment: So, I've successfully changed the alias. BUT, how do I change the number format? I see how I can change the numeric settings once I've added a feature class as a layer in ArcMap, but is there a way to attach this to the dataset itself? Essentially I want to show round numbers and percentages in my javascript legend widget.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: I've changed the alias of the field in ArcMap and that persists
>   in the feature service. But, I'm still wondering: How do I change the
>   number format used in the dijit Legend? (I would like to display
>   rounded numbers and percentages.)

so I'm not completely sure that this what you are looking for, but
inside Arcmap, if you open an attribute table of a feature class, right click a numeric field and choose properties
[image]

in the properties menu select "Numeric Format", you will notice all kind formatting options like:"number of significant digis","thousand speratore", you can even create your own format.
[image]

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, and I tried it. But changing these properties seemed to be attached to the layer in the MXD rather than actual feature class in the GDB. so when I uploaded the GDB to ArcGIS online, the alias and numeric properties I defined were not present

Answer (score 0):

[API Reference](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/classbreaksrenderer-amd.html#infos)

For a class breaks renderer, the class breaks are objects stored in the array `infos`. `minValue`, `maxValue`, and `label` are all properties of these objects. So, when you `generateRenderer`, rather than calling `applyRenderer` immediately, first modify these properties. So here I build a label for each object (0-4 for a 5 class renderer) based on rounding the min and maxValue. I'm sure I could have also done this with a loop rather than for each object individually.

```
   generateRenderer.execute(params, modifyRenderer);
   function modifyRenderer(renderer){
       var minLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[0].minValue * 100);
       var maxLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[0].maxValue * 100);
       renderer.infos[0].label = minLabel0 + " - " + maxLabel0 + "%";
       var minLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[1].minValue * 100);
       var maxLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[1].maxValue * 100);
       renderer.infos[1].label = minLabel0 + " - " + maxLabel0 + "%";
       var minLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[2].minValue * 100);
       var maxLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[2].maxValue * 100);
       renderer.infos[2].label = minLabel0 + " - " + maxLabel0 + "%";
       var minLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[3].minValue * 100);
       var maxLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[3].maxValue * 100);
       renderer.infos[3].label = minLabel0 + " - " + maxLabel0 + "%";
       var minLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[4].minValue * 100);
       var maxLabel0 = Math.round(renderer.infos[4].maxValue * 100);
       renderer.infos[4].label = minLabel0 + " - " + maxLabel0 + "%";
       applyRenderer(renderer);
   };
   function applyRenderer(renderer) {
     featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
     createLegend("Approval Rate");
   };
```

Comment: I think if you set the labels up for the symbology of the feature class within the MXD you are publishing from, that should automatically carry over to the JS API for the Legend.

Comment: Right, but I've got several different attributes I'm mapping (which is why I'm generating renderers). I think I can only set this up for one attribute in the MXD